# Is there any way to see the health of my vehicle?

Tags: state-of-decay-2

Frequently I find myself if bad situations where my saving grace is the vehicle I take with me. I repair every time I return to my homestead but is there anyway to see the current health of my vehicle? I don’t want to try and take on a horde or two if my vehicle is close to blowing up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no actual health bar that will tell you the health of your vehicle.
There are only visual indicators of its health. *(And maybe audio, but I have not noticed any so far. SoD 1 had the ticking noise of the engine)*

If your car has white smoke coming from under the hood, it's definitely time to repair your vehicle and avoid slamming into anything.
I'm also not sure yet how the new system works, SoD 1 had a separate repair option for bodywork and engine while SoD 2 only has 1 repair kit for both.

Comment: Have you killed a juggernaut with a vehicle?  I wonder if the vehicle would survive.

Comment: @ZeroStack No but I have rammed a horde with a vehicle that was (I suppose) at half health and it just instantly blew up as I hit the horde.

Comment: lol oh man ... hopefully there weren’t many rucksacks in the back

Comment: @ZeroStack You don't lose anything when a car blows up, a fully destroyed car can be repaired with a repair kit and will become driveable again. The trunk you can access while its destroyed.

Comment: @Vahx Is it insta-death for the characters in the car when it blows up?

Comment: @katahlyn My character did not die, he just got thrown out of the car and had some health loss due to the impact. I've only had this experience once though, so not sure if a low health character would survive or not.